# How to taylor expand $\Pi_{i=1}^d\frac{\sin x_j}{x_j} = 1-\frac{1}{6}|x|^2 + O(|x|^4)$ as $|x| \to 0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

How do we integrate $\int_C (1-e^{i \langle w,x \rangle})dw$ where $C = [-1,1]^d$?

I am given that the answer is $2^d (1- \Pi_{i=1}^d\frac{\sin x_j}{x_j})$ but I cannot see why.

Also, why do we have that $\Pi_{i=1}^d\frac{\sin x_j}{x_j} = 1-\frac{1}{6}|x|^2 + O(|x|^4)$ as $|x| \to 0$?

I cannot find any explanation on these results and I would greatly appreciate if anyone could show how to derive these results.

**Answer to first question.**

The first integral can be calculated by splitting $1$ from the integrand, and looking at $\int_{-1}^1 e^{iwx}dw = \frac{1}{ix}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix}) = \frac{1}{ix} 2i \sin x = \frac{\sin x}{x}$.

But I am stil struggling with the taylor expansion.

Comment: The exponential is a product of 'indipendent' terms so to speak. You can integrate each variable at the time so that eventually the total integral is a product.

Comment: @lcv okay thank you the trick was to split the $1$ in the integral and just look at the exponential.

Comment: Yes, use linearity of integration :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that
$$
{\sin u\over u}=1-{u^2\over 6}+O(u^4)
$$
hence
$$
\prod_{i=1}^d{\sin x_i\over x_i}{=\prod_{i=1}^d[1-{x_i^2\over 6}+O(x_i^4)]
\\=1-\sum_{i=1}^d{x_i^2\over 6}+\sum_{i=1}^dO(x_i^4)+O(||x||^6)
}
$$
hence the result.